# Return value from function where called

Tags: php

In the following custom function...

```
function get_txtlocal_balance() {
    $username = variable_get('sms_txtlocal_email');
    $hash = variable_get('sms_txtlocal_password');
    $data = array('username' => $username, 'hash' => $hash);
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.txtlocal.com/balance/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $balance = json_decode($response, true);
    echo $balance['balance']['sms'];
}
```

I return a balance from a text local account. Now i try and echo this balance into place...

```
$balance = get_txtlocal_balance();
$title = 'SMS Integration - Current Balance: ' . $balance;

<span><?php echo $title;?></span>
```

But the returned value doesnt appear in the right place, it always returns are the top of the page, can anyone spot what im doing wrong?

Comment: `return $balance['balance']['sms'];`

Comment: Ah christ. haha. Thanks! Post as an answer if you like?

Comment: @u_mulder You're so modest ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Below Code :

```
function get_txtlocal_balance() {
$username = variable_get('sms_txtlocal_email');
$hash = variable_get('sms_txtlocal_password');
$data = array('username' => $username, 'hash' => $hash);
$ch = curl_init('http://api.txtlocal.com/balance/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$balance = json_decode($response, true);
return $balance['balance']['sms'];
}
```